# Overlapping replacements with sed?

Tags: sed, find-and-replace

Suppose I have an input string:

```
,,a,b,c,,,,d,e,f,,,g
```

Is there a simple sed command that can insert something between every pair of consecutive commas? That is, what can I use to convert the input string to:

```
0,0,a,b,c,0,0,0,d,e,f,0,0,g
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a loop with sed:

```
sed 's/^,/0,/; :a; s/,,/,0,/g; ta'
```

Documented here: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Programming-Commands

But I'd use perl or awk

```
perl -pe 's/(?:^|,)\K(?=,|$)/0/g'
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == "") $i=0};1'
```